# My Redux state is getting changed, but it doesn't re-render

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a parent component and a child component. I can see that the reducer is getting an update (Please refer to screenshot) but it is not re-rendering the component. I am calling some API, and once the response comes, it will just update some variable and re-render the component.

**Parent component**

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Tab, Tabs, TabList, TabPanel } from 'react-tabs';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import ProfileInfo from '../components/Profile/ProfileInfo'
import Details from '../components/Profile/Details'
import UnitSpec from '../components/Profile/UnitSpec'
import * as profileActionCreators from "./../actions/profileActions";
import * as StaticData from '../utils/country'


class NewProfilePage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { tabIndex: 0 ,
     countryList: StaticData.Country,

    };
    let { dispatch } = this.props
    this.actions = bindActionCreators({...profileActionCreators} , dispatch);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   console.log('nextProps', nextProps)
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="admin-holder">
            <div className="row profile-row">

                <div className="small-12 large-4 columns">
                    <ProfileInfo></ProfileInfo>
                </div>
                <div className="small-12 large-8 columns">
                  <Tabs selectedIndex={this.state.tabIndex} onSelect={tabIndex => this.setState({ tabIndex })}>
             <TabList>
               <Tab>Details</Tab>
               <Tab>Unit Spec</Tab>
               <Tab>Imaginery</Tab>
               <Tab>Menu</Tab>
             </TabList>
              <TabPanel> 
             <Details updateDetails = {(userDetail) => this.actions.updateDetails(userDetail)} countryList={this.state.countryList}/>
              </TabPanel>
              <TabPanel> 
               <UnitSpec staticData={StaticData}/>
              </TabPanel>
              <TabPanel> 
              </TabPanel>
              <TabPanel> 
              </TabPanel>
         </Tabs>
    </div>
   </div>

   </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps= (state) => {
 console.log('state', state)
 return{
      profileReducer: state.profileReducer
 };
};



export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NewProfilePage);
```

**Reducer**

```js
import * as types from '../constant';


const initialCommonState = {
   countryList: [],
   loadingCountryList: false,
   isProfileUpdated: false
}




const profileReducer = (state=initialCommonState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
        case types.UPDATE_DETAILS + "_FULFILLED":
         const response = action.payload;
         return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    isProfileUpdated: true
                  });

        case types.UPDATE_DETAILS + "_PENDING":
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    isProfileUpdated: false
                  });

        case types.UPDATE_DETAILS + "_REJECTED":
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                    isProfileUpdated: false
                  });

        default : 
         return state    
 }

}

export default profileReducer;
```

**Please look into screenshot as well and you can see "isProfileUpdated" is changed to true**
[image]

**Store**

```js
import {createStore,combineReducers,applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import logger from 'redux-logger';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import promise from 'redux-promise-middleware'
import reducers from '../reducers';

const middleware = [];
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    middleware.push(logger);
}

export default createStore(
    combineReducers({reducers}),
    {},
    //applyMiddleware(logger(),thunk , promise())
    applyMiddleware(logger, thunk , promise())
)
```

Comment: As the answer implies it’s usually a good idea to also include your store setup; you’re probably not using object shorthand. You can also put logs or breakpoints in your `mapStateToProps` as a sanity check.

Answer (score 0):

Your state contains profile

```
const mapStateToProps= (state) => {
    console.log('state', state)
    return{
         profileReducer: state.profile
    };
};
```